# Adding Second Border to JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Here's the issue: When I try to add a border to a JButton via setBorder(), the normal background styling of the button:

> [image: correct]

disappears, to be replaced by what is essentially a clickable JLabel:

> [image: incorrect]

Basically, what I'd like to do is add a colored border around the current default border. If there's another process other than using setBorder() that would work, I would be interested in hearing about it.

Also, I should add that I cannot subclass or override methods of the graphics elements, as this needs to be inserted as a standalone tool in a far larger code repository.

Edit: Specifying question better

Comment: What type of border are you wanting? I'm thinking maybe the reason why it looks like a clickable JLabel is because you are replacing the default shadowed border.

Comment: Just a normal colored border; the intention is for it to act as a "highlight" or sorts, to draw attention to it in the overall interface. That's an interesting point; I'll look into it.

Comment: Indeed, changing the border to a new'ed JButton's border restores it to how it should be. Perhaps I should edit the question to be adding a second border to a JButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a compound border. You can do this:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("BUTTON TEXT");
myButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(myButton.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
```

This will preserve the look/feel of the button and will add a red border.